# Difference between Cells and Range in computing average

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose there are 5 numbers `103.6, 104.8, 106.2 , 105.7,105.6` in cells `[E2:E6]`. If I run `=AVERAGE` over these 5 numbers, then I get `105.18`.

However, I do the following in the immediate window in VBA. I will get a different answer.

`?worksheetfunction.Average(cells(2,"E"), cells(6,"E"))
 104.6`

But if I use range instead of cells, the answer is correct.

`?worksheetfunction.Average(range("E2:E6")) 
 105.18`

Why is there such difference using cells and range for such an easy computation ? This really confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because `WorksheetFunction.Average(Cells(2,"E"), Cells(6,"E"))` takes average of only two cells `E2` and `E6`. If you want to get average of entire range, use

```
WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(2,"E"), Cells(6,"E")))
```

or direct `WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("E2:E6"))` as you used it.

Also for reliability I suggets you to fully qualify your range:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(2, "E"), .Cells(6, "E")))
End With
```